# How do I modify this tree node insertion logic to result into a balanced binary tree?

Tags: php, binary-tree

I am new to coding for trees.

Given the following input array -

```
array(10,7,13,5,6,8,11,15,14,4,3,16)
```

I would like to prepare a balanced binary tree by inserting these values one by one, starting from the first element (left child of a node should be inserted, then right child, then the next node should be checked to insert it's left and right children. All insertions should happen to a level first, before inserting to a higher level). The result should appear like this -

[image]

Here is the code I have now (modified a bit from a BST code that I found [here](https://gist.github.com/igutman/11a5403b5d106f12c4e5))

```
<?php


class Node
{

    public $left;
    public $right;
    public $data;

    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
        $this->right = NULL;
        $this->left = NULL;
    }

} //End class Node

class BTree
{

    public $root;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->root = NULL;
    }

    /* Insert the first node to the BST*/
    public function insert($data)
    {

        $node = new Node($data);

        if($this->root === NULL)
                $this->root = $node;
        else 
            $this->insertNode($this->root,$node);

    }

    /* Insert node starting from root */
    public function insertNode(&$root,$node)
    {
            if($root === NULL)
            {//root is not occupied, set root as the node
                $root = $node;
            }
            else
            {   
                if($root->left && $root->left->data===null) 
                {
                    $root->left==$node;
                }
                else 
                {
                    if($root->right && $root->right->data===null) //Not using else to avoid duplicate values
                    {
                        $root->right==$node;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $this->insertNode($root->left,$node); //Search for place in the right side to insert        
                    }
                }
            }       
    }

    /* Get an array and insert all items in it to the tree in the array order */
    public function multiInsert($array)
    {

        foreach($array as $data)
            $this->insert($data);
    }


    /*
    Draw the tree from left to right
    Line with same color are in same level of the tree
    */
    public function draw($node = 'root', $depth = 0)
    {

        if($node == 'root') $node = $this->root; /* If node not selected the default is the tree root */

        if ($node === null) return;

        return
            $this->draw($node->right, $depth + 1).str_repeat("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;", $depth).
            "<span style='color:".(($depth%2 == 0)? 'red' : 'blue')."'>".$node->data."</span><br>".
            $this->draw($node->left, $depth + 1);
    }

} //End class BTree


/* ########### EXAMPLE ########### */
echo '<h1>Binary Tree</h1>';
$tree = new BTree();
$tree->multiInsert(array(10,7,13,5,6,8,11,15,14,4,3,16));
echo'<br><br>';
echo $tree->draw();

?>
```

This is resulting into a tree with only left children, as shown in the following output -

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
if($root->left && $root->left->data===null) 
   ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You initialize your nodes to be `null`, so `$root->left`, being null, will evaluate to `false`, sending you down the `else` path. `$root->right` is also null, so you go down to `insertNode($root->left)`, where you do finally end up with a null node, and assign it to `left` unconditionally.

You should be doing

```
if (is_null($root->left)) {
    $root->left = $node
} else if (is_null($root->right)) {
    $root->right = $node;
} else (
    $this->insertNode(...);
}
```

Comment: yay for php's drunken naming conventions... fixed.

Comment: Ah, I see. But, on doing this change as you suggested, I am getting only 10 (the first node) in the output. http://codepad.org/v66zZq7a (html in the output is not rendering), but you can see.